# Create a Generic list of <T>

Tags: c#, list, generics

I want to create a method that will create a List of generic objects. Is it possible? Something like this:

```
public class Mtrl 
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }        
    public string Aa { get; set; }
}

public class Trdr 
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string AFM { get; set; }
    public string Phone01 { get; set; }
    public string Aa { get; set; }
}
```

And then with a generic class to create my list:

```
public class GenericClass<T>
{        
    public List<T> GetData<T>()
    {
        List<T> myList = new List<T>();
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(Trdr))
        {
            myList.Add(new Trdr());//Error 1: cannot convert from Trdr to 'T'   
        }
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(Mtrl))//Error 2: cannot convert from Mtrl to 'T'    
        {
            myList.Add(new Mtrl());
        }
        return myList;
    }
}
```

My mistake. I will try to clarify more. The Classes Trdr,Mtrl etc will have many different properties. The Getdata method will take data from a web service via json and i want to create a List of Objects and return it
Something like this:

```
public List<T> GetData<T>()
        {
            List<T> myList = new List<T>();
            if (typeof(T) == typeof(Trdr))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)//fetch data from web api in json format
                {
                    Trdr NewObj = new Trdr();
                    NewObj.Aa = "...";
                    NewObj.AFM = "...";

                    myList.Add(NewObj);
                }
            }
            if (typeof(T) == typeof(Mtrl))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                {
                    Mtrl NewObj = new Mtrl();
                    NewObj.Aa = "...";
                    NewObj.Name = "name ...";

                    myList.Add(NewObj);
                }
            }
            return myList;
        }
    }
```

Comment: but `List<T>` is already generic? You literally don't need to do this?

Comment: While you _could_ just add a cast there is a safe mechanism for this: add the `new` constraint `public List<T> GetData<T>() where T : new() { /* code */ list.Add(new T()); }`. However I wonder what you're trying to do here, what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Why can't you create 2 methods for this? Alternatively you could invoke `List<T>.Add` through reflection, though i don't think that should be _the_ solution here. Or you can add an `interface` to both classes and use `where T : IMyInterface` in the method signature.

Comment: a **generic** method that only works for two specific types isn´t really **generic**, is it? Unless both your classes aher the same base-class or -interface, you shouldn´t use generics here. Apart from this you seem to add only a single element, making a **list** pretty pointless. Or is this just demo?

Comment: `public List<T> GetData<T>() Where T : new { return new List<T>(){new T()};` ? Though this is completely redundant as is

Comment: Beside the Trdr and the Mtrl Class i will create about 20 more classes and i asked the question because i want to have the only one GetData function if it is possible.

Comment: Side note: it seems, that both `Mtrl` and `Trdr` at least share some *interface*, say `Irl {Id, Name, Code, Aa}` and you, probably, want `List<Irl>` as a collection which can contain items of either `Mtrl` or `Trdr`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest extracting an *interface* (or even a *base class*):

```
 //TODO: Since you have more than 2 classes, please check the common interface 
 public interface Idr {
   string Id   { get; set; }
   string Name { get; set; }
   string Code { get; set; }        
   string Aa   { get; set; }
 }
```

With all classes of interest implementing it:

```
public class Mtrl : Idr
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }        
    public string Aa { get; set; }
}

public class Trdr : Idr 
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Aa { get; set; }

    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string AFM { get; set; }
    public string Phone01 { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can use `List<Idr>` collection; we want the class (`T`) that implements `Idr` to have a parameterless constructor as well (`new()`):

```
public class GenericClass<T> where T : Idr, new()
{        
    public List<T> GetData()
    {
        List<T> myList = new List<T>() {
          new T();
        };

        return myList;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are trying to create a new list that contains some initial data, and you need to do this for many different types `T`.

If `Mtrl` and `Trdr` has nothing in common and are handled completely differently, consider simply using different methods to get each type of list:

```
GetDataMtrl(){
    var result = new List<Mtrl>();
    result.Add(new Mtrl());
    return result;
} // etc
```

Otherwise what you need is [Type Constraints of Generic Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters), that can tell the compiler more about what `T` is. Or rather what the different values of `T` must have in common. For example you can do

```
    public List<T> GetData<T>() where T : new()
    {
        List<T> myList = new List<T>();

        myList.Add(new T());

        return myList;
    }
```

To say that for `T` it has to be possible to do `new T()`. Then you can say `GetData<Trdr>()` to get a list that contains a single empty `Trdr`, as you code might seem to try to do.

Maybe you need to set some default values in the data. I notice the classes has a lot of variables in common. Then you might consider using inheritance to specify this commonality:

```
public class Mtrl 
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }        
    public string Aa { get; set; }
}

public class Trdr : Mtrl
{
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string AFM { get; set; }
    public string Phone01 { get; set; }
}
```

And then write generic code where `T` is either of the type `Mtrl` or its descendant class:

```
    public List<T> GetData<T>() where T : Mtrl
    {
        List<T> myList = new List<T>();
        T MtrlOrTrdr = new T();
        MtrlOrTrdr.Id = "my-new-id-";

        myList.Add(MtrlOrTrdr);

        return myList;
    }
```